# iPad javascript error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad

I have a small chunk of code that crashes my iPad.  It works fine in every other browser I test it on (Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer 7+). But if fails on my iPad.

```
var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;

$('li .staffPicker').each(function() {
    if(count == randomStaff){
        $(this).addClass('staffPickHover');
        $('.staffChoice').html(staffPickDisplay[randomStaff]);
        orientation = adjustStaffPickSize('.staffPickPhoto img');

        if (!isiPad){ 
            **$('.staffPickPhoto img').addClass(orientation);**
        }

        $('.reviewNum').each(function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    } 
    count++;
});
```

I am currently checking to see if the person is using an iPad and just skipping the line of code which causes the program to fail, but I would rather fix the code itself.  Especially considering it might not work on iPhones and the problem might be fixed in different versions of iOS.

The website in question is www.bookcellarinc.com

Comment: Have you tried using the Safari Remote Web Debugger?

Comment: What is the line that is failing ? Also what does `adjustStaffPickSize` return

Comment: This is the line that fails

$('.staffPickPhoto img').addClass(orientation);

Comment: It might be a iOS 5.1 problem.  I have an iPad 1 and so I don't have the most recent OS